# Why does JavaScript's "in" operator return false incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

You're able to replicate by so:

```
var test = {'var1': 'bacon'};

"var1" in test;             // Returns true  - Correct
!"var1" in test;            // Returns false - Correct
"nonexistant" in test;      // Returns false - Correct
!"nonexistant" in test;     // Returns false - Incorrect - This should be true.. should it not?
```

Comment: Compare with `(!"x") in test` and `!("x" in test)` (replacing x for all the cases above) - and that should lead to the conclusion ..

Comment: `!"string"` => `false`, so in both cases it is reporting the correct result: `false` is not in `test`.

Comment: The `in` operator doesn't do anything incorrectly. It can't. It has no choice. It's mere syntax, the behavior of which is governed by is implementation in accordance with the ECMAScript specification. If you're not getting the response you'd like, that means your code is written incorrectly.

Comment: @thesystem—or expecting the wrong result. ;-)

Comment: So the best way to test whether operator is NOT false would be to compare the returned result against a boolean? ie. if(("var2" in test) !== true) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `in` operator binds fairly loosely.  It's generally a good idea to parenthesize `in` subexpressions.

Thus, `!"var1" in test` is parsed as `(!"var1") in test` for example.

Comment: …which is effectively converted to `'false' in test` for the comparison.